# Python unexpected NoneType in print()

Tags: python-3.x

I am experiencing some strange behavior in one of my python scripts.

I have a function which calculates the last connected date of an interface on a switch port.

```
def last_change(self):
    """
    Gets the date from the last time the interface status changed.
    ifLastChange time is relevant to sysUpTime and should thus be calculated as: sysUpTime-ifLastChange/100
    The ifLastChange and sysUpTime values are `Ticks` and should be handled as UNIX-Time
    :return: Date as string. Format DD.MM:YYYY hh:mm:ss
    """
    self.snmp_obj.mib = 'IF-MIB'
    self.snmp_obj.mib_object = 'ifLastChange'
    self.snmp_obj.match = self.ifindex
    snmp_response = self.snmp_obj.snmp_get_specific()
    sys_ticks = Switch.uptime(self)
    int_ticks = snmp_response[1].strip("'")
    tick_diff = int(sys_ticks) - int(int_ticks)
    chtime = datetime.timedelta(seconds=tick_diff / 100)
    print((datetime.datetime.today() - chtime).strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'))
    return str((datetime.datetime.today() - chtime).strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'))
```

I call the function on my `interface` object in my code as follows:

```
            print(interface.last_change())
            print('HOSTNAME: ' + device_hostname +
                            '\nUSERNAME: ' + device_user +
                            '\nIFNAME: ' + ifname +
                            '\nIFINDEX: ' + ifindex +
                            '\nBPI: ' + bpi +
                            '\nIFSTATUS: ' + ifstatus +
                            '\nVLAN: ' + ifvlan +
                            '\nMAC: ' + mac_address +
                            '\nTRUNKSTATUS: ' + trunk_status +
                            '\nPORTSEC_STATE: ' + interface.portsec_state() +
                            '\nPORTSEC_STATUS: ' + interface.portsec_status() +
                            '\nMAXMAC: ' + interface.max_macaddresses() +
                            '\nLAST_CHNAGE: ' + interface.last_change())
```

Now interestingly, `print(interface.last_change())` works, but in the "big" `print()` function an error is raised.

```
02.07.2016 10:09:27
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "portfynder.py", line 171, in <module>
    main()
  File "portfynder.py", line 140, in main
    '\nLAST_CHNAGE: ' + interface.last_change())
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType
```

As seen in the output above, `print(interface.last_change())` works and also returns a `str` value (`02.07.2016 10:09:27`). But for some reason it returns a `NoneType` in the big `print()` function.

I have no idea why this is happening, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by a different value being `None` than the one the error mentions, Python can't point to specific parts when you split a line across multiple so it will pick that last line.

```
print('1: ' + '1' +
      '\n2: ' + '2'
      '\n3: ' + None +
      '\n4: ' + '4' +
      '\n5: ' + '5')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python Scripts\test.py", line 8, in <module>
    '\n5: ' + '5')
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType
```

Is the same as

```
print('1: ' + '1' + '\n2: ' + '2' + '\n3: ' + None + '\n4: ' + '4' + '\n5: ' + '5')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python Scripts\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    print('1: ' + '1' + '\n2: ' + '2' + '\n3: ' + None + '\n4: ' + '4' + '\n5: ' + '5')
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType
```

So you need to figure out which of the other values are resulting in `None`. I would also suggest using `str.format` as it doesn't have any of the issues that string concatenation does. So even if `None` gets passed you can still see it in the output. Otherwise you'd have to cast the `None` value to a string to concatenate it.

```
print('1: {}\n2: {}\n3: {}\n4: {}\n5: {}'
      .format('1', '2', None, '4', '5'))

1: 1
2: 2
3: None
4: 4
5: 5
```